# .htaccess rewrite id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to prevent a "messy" URL for people to see, when they hover over the link. Like this one:

http://screensnapr.com/v/4z84A3.png

Now, I have it in the .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^forms/([0-9]+).*/?$ _lib/forms/report.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but apparently I'm doing something wrong. This is my link:

```
<a style="float: right;padding-right: 15px; color: #3BC3C0;" href="../../_lib/forms/report.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" rel="facebox"><img src="../../_lib/images/notice.png"></a>
```

Do you guys happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want people to see instead of the 'messy' URL? Post an example if possible.

Comment: something like <a href="#">Report</a> but that "#" is still doing the same function as "href="../../_lib/forms/report.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule forms/(\d+)/.*$ /foldername/foldername/_lib/forms/report.php?id=$1
```

HTML

```
<a style="float: right;padding-right: 15px; color: #3BC3C0;" href="/foldername/foldername/_lib/forms/report.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" rel="facebox"><img src="/foldername/foldername/_lib/images/notice.png"></a>
```

You need to use absolute urls for your links so don't use ../../_lib/forms use **/foldername/foldername/_lib/forms/** then update the path portion in the rewrite rule I have with that path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^forms/([0-9]\d*)/.*$ /_lib/forms/report.php?id=$1
```

This is assuming your _lib directory is in the Document Root of the website. It's better to provide an explicit path to the PHP file from the Document Root.

Comment: the php file from root is public_html/_lib/forms/report.php the php file where you'd view the link is public_html/media/article.php